# Problem in writing more record to berkeleyDB

Tags: java, berkeley-db

```
i am using berkeley DB JE 4.1.10
i have use the secondary database concept and I want to insert 10,00,000 rows to the database .

i am getting following error

Exception in thread "main" com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: (JE 4.1.10) JAVA_ERROR: Java Error occurred, recovery may not be possible.
at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkIfInvalid(EnvironmentImpl.java:1450)
at com.sleepycat.je.Transaction.checkEnv(Transaction.java:756)
at com.sleepycat.je.Transaction.abort(Transaction.java:105)
at WriteDataUsingCursor.main(WriteDataUsingCursor.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

i have set the following parameter for environment and database


Environment env=null;
Database primarydb=null;
SecondaryDatabase secondarydb=null;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
TupleBinding mybinding=null;
String firstdb="CDRFirstDatabase";
String seconddb = "CDRSecondDatabase";

public void setupenvironment()
{
try
{
// Environment

File dbpath = new File("W:/dhananjay/workspace/BDB-SecondaryDatabase(JEAPI)-SmaxCDR/src/DB1");
EnvironmentConfig envconfig = new EnvironmentConfig();
envconfig.setAllowCreate(true);
envconfig.setTransactional(true);
env = new Environment(dbpath,envconfig);

// Primary Database

DatabaseConfig dbconfig = new DatabaseConfig();
dbconfig.setAllowCreate(true);
dbconfig.setTransactional(true);
dbconfig.setSortedDuplicates(false);

primarydb = env.openDatabase(null, firstdb, dbconfig);

// Secondary Database

SecondaryConfig secondarydbconfig = new SecondaryConfig();
secondarydbconfig.setAllowCreate(true);
secondarydbconfig.setTransactional(true);
secondarydbconfig.setSortedDuplicates(true);

// Create Key for secondary DB

mybinding = new MyTupleBinding();
SecondaryKey keycreator = new SecondaryKey(mybinding);
secondarydbconfig.setKeyCreator(keycreator);
secondarydb = env.openSecondaryDatabase(null, seconddb, primarydb, secondarydbconfig);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("Error----->"+e);
}
}

i am using following code to insert the data into database

DBEnvironment dbenv = new DBEnvironment();
DatabaseEntry theKey = new DatabaseEntry();
DatabaseEntry theData = new DatabaseEntry();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Cursor cursor = null;
Transaction txn=null;
dbenv.setupenvironment();
try
{
txn = dbenv.getEnv().beginTransaction(null, null);
cursor = dbenv.getPrimaryDB().openCursor(txn, null);
String line = null;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("W:/dhananjay/workspace/SMAXCDR/110618_154501.cdr"));
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{

String[] sArray = line.split(",");
CDRData cdrfile = new CDRData();
theKey = new DatabaseEntry(sArray[0].getBytes("UTF-8"));
cdrfile.setId(sArray[0]);
cdrfile.setCallTime(sArray[1]);
cdrfile.setDisconnectTime(sArray[2]);
cdrfile.setIngressTrunkID(sArray[3]);
cdrfile.setIngressSignalingIP(sArray[4]);
cdrfile.setIngressMediaIP(sArray[5]);
cdrfile.setEgressTrunkID(sArray[6]);
cdrfile.setEgressSignalingIP(sArray[7]);
cdrfile.setEgressMediaIP(sArray[8]);
cdrfile.setANI(sArray[9]);
cdrfile.setDNID(sArray[10]);
cdrfile.setDNID_with_IngressPrefix(sArray[11]);
cdrfile.setDNID_with_EgressPrefix(sArray[12]);
cdrfile.setCodeMatch(sArray[13]);
cdrfile.setProtocol(sArray[14]);
cdrfile.setCallID(sArray[15]);
cdrfile.setSMaxCallID(sArray[16]);
cdrfile.setRingDuration(sArray[17]);
cdrfile.setPDDDuration(sArray[18]);
cdrfile.setRawDuration(sArray[19]);
cdrfile.setCauseCode(sArray[20]);
cdrfile.setTFlag(sArray[21]);
cdrfile.setRFlag(sArray[22]);
dbenv.getBinding().objectToEntry(cdrfile, theData);
cursor.put(theKey, theData);

}
cursor.close();
txn.commit();
dbenv.close();
long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("The time taken by insert query : "(finishTime-startTime) " ms");
System.out.println("Record Inserted");
}
```

Comment: By lakh do you mean 100,000? If so, could you please edit it. And be more specific in how you insert the records.

Answer (score 1):

Cursors and transactions hang on to memory until they are closed/committed. You'll need to insert in batches, perhaps 1000. For each batch, close the cursor when done, commit the transaction, and then create new ones for the next batch.

Comment: I have implemented what you've suggested and it's working like a charm and the performance improved significantly. But the issue is, when ever I'm inserting records in batch and committing the transactions, if an exception is thrown due to error while processing, already committed records also needs to be rolled back. Here, we need to account on the ATOMICITY. How to deal with such scenario?

Comment: Atomicity -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems) -- implies that either all of the operations in a transaction succeed or none of them do. Berkeley DB *is* implementing atomic transactions. If an error occurs within the transaction, then all of the operations within that transaction must be aborted. One option that you can try is to use smaller batches, so that you don't have to re-process as many records.

Comment: That's correct. But, let's say I have 100K records to insert. Now, I am inserting records in batches, perhaps 10K. Now, assume that somewhat 60K records are inserted and committed successfully in batches and after that while processing records from 60001 to 70000, I am having an exception. So, only these 60001 to 70000 records are rolled back. But we also need to roll back 1 - 60000 records for having Atomicity for all the records. Now, how to achieve atomicity for such smaller batches which have inserted chunk of records earlier?